# Instancing PhpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I was looking for functions to send email messages, and decided to use PhpMailer, as it's quite simple to use. But i got this question about it (and wasn't been able to resolve it reading manuals) - is PhpMailer should be instanced like PDO, representing one general handler, or one instance represents one email message?

Comment: I think the answer is "One General Handler" but are you trying to send multiple emails all from that same script? Not SPAM of course, would never suggets that

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just trying to figure out, should i build it like PDO instance (has constructor where i define SMTP settings and all that stuff, and separate functions like setTargets, setOrigin, setReplyTo, etc.).... oh, i think now i figured it out, but not sure...

Comment: Perhaps read the docs and examples, especially the mailing list one, and also the wiki notes about sending to lists.

Comment: @Syncro thanks for directions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found PHPMailer a bit confusing in that regard too, as you can configure things like SMTP (which is more of a transport matter), but also the message itself. So PHPMailer has two concerns to manage: the message and how to send it.

That said: I would indeed use a new instance of PHPMailer for each message but have a factory create it to take care of the transport (e.g. SMTP) and/ or things that might not change like the sender of the message.

(That way you can send different messages with the same configuration for transport and sender. Another benefit of this approach is: you can change the transport for the entire site in one location: the factory.)